# Pass value to creating an Actor handling websocket Play 2

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I accept websocket messages in following way:

```
  def socket = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[ChatCommand, JsValue] { request =>
    Future.successful(request.session.get("login") match {
      case None => Left(Forbidden)
      case Some(_) => Right(ChatActor.props)
    })
  }
```

How can i pass the value of "login" to actor?

Edit:

```
object ChatActor{
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new ChatActor(out))
 ....
}

class ChatActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = ...

}
```

And when i change props i have no out to supply in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Chat actor is something like

```
object ChatActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef, login: String): Props = Props(new ChatActor(out, login))
}

class ChatActor(out: ActorRef, login: String) extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = ???
}
```

Then your should code

```
  def socket = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[ChatCommand, JsValue] { request =>
    Future.successful(request.session.get("login") match {
      case None => Left(Forbidden)
      case Some(login) => Right(out => ChatActor.props(out, login))
    })
  }
```

You might find interesting http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Props

Comment: That's what i tried to do. But play2 websocket actors are special. They need out actorref as a parameter which is somehow magically supplied to props. I'll update my post immediately. That's my bad i provided too little example code.

Comment: What I previously was calling upstream is what you called out. Out is a better name. :)